# Error " prettier/prettier: Delete `·· ` " while setting up prettier on vim

Tags: vim, eslint, prettier, editorconfig

I created a NextJs project and I wanted to integrate Prettier ans Eslint to help me out.
Here's my config files:

.prettierrc

```
{                                                                               
     "trailingComma": "es5",                                                       
    "semi": true,                                                                 
    "singleQuote": true,                                                          
    "tabWidth": 2,                                                                
    "endOfLine": "auto"        
}
```

.eslintrc

```
   {                                                                               
     "plugins": ["prettier"],                                                      
     "extends": ["prettier"],                                                      
     "rules": {                                                                    
       "prettier/prettier": "error"                                                
     },                                                                            
   "parserOptions": {                                                              
         "ecmaVersion": 7,                                                         
        "sourceType": "module",                                                   
        "ecmaFeatures": {                                                         
            "jsx": true,                                                          
        }                                                                         
    }                                                                             
  }
```

I also have a .editor config file

```
# EditorConfig is awesome: http://EditorConfig.org                              
  2                                                                                 
  3 # top-most EditorConfig file                                                    
  4 root = true                                                                     
  5                                                                                 
  6 # Unix-style newlines with a newline ending every file                          
  7 [*]                                                                             
  8 end_of_line = lf                                                                
  9 insert_final_newline = true                                                     
 10 indent_style = space                                                            
 11 indent_size = 4                                                                 
 12 charset = utf-8                                                                 
 13                                                                                 
 14 [*.{js,json}]                                                                   
 15 indent_size = 2                                                                 
 16                                                                                                                
 17 [*.sql]                                                                                                        
 18 indent_size = 8
```

When save my files, I get the error

```
prettier/prettier: Delete `··`
```

Can someone help me out?

Answer (score 0):

there is a conflict between `.prettierrc` and `.editorconfig`. ESLint will only follow what is in the `.prettierrc`. In your case, your file is following `.editorconfig` rule (that overwrites what is in `.prettierrc`) but your ESLint is following `.prettierrc` rule.

in your `.prettierrc`,

```json
"tabWidth": 2
```

in your `.editorconfig`,

```
indent_size = 4
```

you can either set `"tabWidth": 4` or remove `indent_size = 4` to resolve the problem (depends on whether you prefer 2 or 4).

in fact these parameters in `.editorconfig`

```
end_of_line
indent_style
indent_size/tab_width
max_line_length
```

will conflict with these in `.prettierrc`

```
"endOfLine"
"useTabs"
"tabWidth"
"printWidth"
```

you can either let `.editorconfig` to follow `.prettierrc` default or sync both `.editorconfig` and `.prettierrc` for things to work properly.